# Are the amount of watts to be collected on the Pokewalker cumulative?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

I am trying to unlock the Quiet Cave, and I would like to know if the amount of watts collected to unlock it have to be collected in one sitting, or whether it's the amount of watts collected cumulatively/overall?

Also: Do watts collected before the National Pokédex count towards it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, watts collected before the National Dex count, and you need to get a cumulative total of 100,000 watts. You don't have to do it in one setting, it just unlocks when your total watts are at least 100,000.